# Unusual symbol in equation

Tags: equations, symbols

How can I type the following in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "I have a problem" -- what exactly is the problem? Is it how to install a TeX distribution, how to open a text editor, or something else? Please clarify what the issue, or issues, may be.

Comment: @Mico thanks. I do not know the codes for this square.

Comment: detexify can help you draw and find some latex to start from http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @LaurentDuval - I did actually check with detexify to find out if a large open square symbol existed (and coming up empty) before providing an answer that builds the symbol from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the main issues are, how to create a large open square symbol, center it on the math axis, and have it act as a math operator, i.e., place its argument below (and above, if there's an upper limit) the large open square. Sort of like `\sum`, right? A series of `\vcenter`, `\hbox`, and repeated `\mathlarger` instructions applied to the `\Box` macro solve these issues. (If you compare the following screenshot with the preceding one, you'll notice that the letter `g` to the left of the box is placed ever so slightly higher now.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,  % for "\DeclareMathOperator*" macro
            amsfonts, % for "\Box" macro
            relsize}  % for "\mathlarger" macro
\newcommand{\BigBox}{\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger 
     {\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\Box}}}}}$}}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigsquare}{\BigBox}

\begin{document}
\[
Z_{\mathcal{T}/G}\equiv \sum_{h\in G}\frac{1}{|G|} 
     \sum_{g\in G} g {\bigsquare_{\textstyle h}}
\]
\end{document}
```

*Addendum* -- Another way to create `\BigBox` is to load the `graphicx` package and to run

```
\newcommand{\BigBox}{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{$\Box$}}}}
```

As you've indicated in a comment that `\BigBox` isn't an "operator" but a partition function with boundary conditions, I think it makes sense -- from a LaTeX point of view -- to define a macro called, say `\partfunc`, that takes two arguments, here: `g` and `h`, and to align the first argument on the math axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,  % for "\DeclareMathOperator*" macro
            amsfonts, % for "\Box" macro
            graphicx} % for "\scalebox" macro
\newcommand\BigBox{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{$\Box$}}}}
\newcommand\bigsquare{\mathop{\BigBox}\limits}
\newcommand\partfunc[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\textstyle #1$}}{\bigsquare_{\textstyle #2}}}

\begin{document}
\[
Z_{\mathcal{T}/G}\equiv \sum_{h\in G}\frac{1}{|G|} 
     \sum_{g\in G} \partfunc{g}{h}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @far - Just out of idle curiosity: What does the large open square symbol "do"? Is it a math operator of some kind?

Comment: it is not an operator.it represents the partition function with boundary condition of free bosons (or free fermions), in conformal field theory and string theory.

Comment: @far - Thanks for this additional explanation. I've updated the answer to show a second approach, with an explicit macro called `\partfunc` (short for partition function).

Answer (score 2):

Geometric shape? Use `picture` mode!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\farsquare}[2]{#1\,{\mathpalette\far@square{#2}}}
\newcommand{\far@square}[2]{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \roundjoin
    \polyline(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,0)(0,0)(0,0.5)
    \end{picture}%
  }}}\limits_{#1#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
Z_{\mathcal{T}/G}\equiv
\sum_{h\in G}\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \farsquare{g}{h}
\]

\[
\textstyle
Z_{\mathcal{T}/G}\equiv
\sum_{h\in G}\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \farsquare{g}{h}
\]

\end{document}
```

The second display emulates text style, just to see that the symbol scales well.

[image]